# How to make changes to time column based on current status and previous status in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data frame has four columns: P_Id, Prev_State, Current_State, Timestamp.

As the process goes through multiple states, the user might have the same timestamp for all the states. I want to add a timestamp value(1 s) for every data point as the process transitions from 1 state to another.

By comparing and matching the Prev_State with the Current_State, corresponding timestamp of that data point is modified by adding 1 s. However, if the timestamp value is different from the previous data point, then I would want to keep the original timestamp.

Note: My timestamp values are in the interval of 30 minutes.

```
P_Id   Prev_State   Current_State   Timestamp
001    None          Initial        2019-02-13 18:00:00   
001    Ready         Loading        2019-02-13 18:00:00
001    Initial       Ready          2019-02-13 18:00:00
001    Loading       Executing      2019-02-13 18:30:00
001    Executing     Evaluating     2019-02-13 18:30:00
001    Evaluating    Terminating    2019-02-13 18:30:00
```

Expected Output:

```
P_Id   Prev_State   Current_State   Timestamp
001    None          Initial        2019-02-13 18:00:00   
001    Ready         Loading        2019-02-13 18:00:02
001    Initial       Ready          2019-02-13 18:00:01
001    Loading       Executing      2019-02-13 18:30:00
001    Executing     Evaluating     2019-02-13 18:30:01
001    Evaluating    Terminating    2019-02-13 18:30:02
```

I am a newbie to python. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the second case, how do you know to start with "Loading" as the :00 time? It seems like this requires you to first find the correct ordering that allows you to chain everything together. Still a fairly cool problem, the chaining being the real hurdle IMO :D

Comment: @ALollz Every time the process enters a new state, its time is recorded,however the time recorded is in the intervals of 30 minutes only. SO the loading, Executing and Evaluating might actually occur @ 18.30.00, 18.36.03, 18.45.06 but recorded time is the beginning of the interval

Comment: The order has to be identified by matching the Current State and Prev_State. For my data, the rows are random and not in the right order. I deliberately swapped the first two rows as my entire data set is not in the order.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with some fun `networkx`. We create a directed graph, then form the longest path. (Ideally your DataFrame is always connected by a single path like in the example). Then we order it, using an ordered Categorical so we can sort.  Finally, add 1s for each new entry and return the Series.

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def add_second(gp):
    # Get Path
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(gp, source='Prev_State', target='Current_State',
                                create_using=nx.DiGraph())
    order = nx.dag_longest_path(G)[:-1]

    # Order
    gp['Prev_State'] = pd.Categorical(gp.Prev_State, ordered=True, categories=order)
    gp = gp.sort_values('Prev_State')

    # Add 1s
    s = gp.Timestamp + pd.to_timedelta(range(len(gp)), unit='s')
    return s

df['new_time'] = df.groupby(['P_Id', 'Timestamp'], group_keys=False).apply(add_second)
```

#### Output:

```
   P_Id  Prev_State Current_State           Timestamp            new_time
0     1        None       Initial 2019-02-13 18:00:00 2019-02-13 18:00:00
1     1       Ready       Loading 2019-02-13 18:00:00 2019-02-13 18:00:02
2     1     Initial         Ready 2019-02-13 18:00:00 2019-02-13 18:00:01
3     1     Loading     Executing 2019-02-13 18:30:00 2019-02-13 18:30:00
4     1   Executing    Evaluating 2019-02-13 18:30:00 2019-02-13 18:30:01
5     1  Evaluating   Terminating 2019-02-13 18:30:00 2019-02-13 18:30:02
```

Comment: Thank you very much. When I tried this solution on my sample data set, it was perfectly working for it but when I applied on my full data set, I get an error: "Graph contains a cycle or graph changed during iteration". I think its because my data has certain data points for which the Current State and Prev State are same in a group.

Comment: @Jupyter Yes, that will cause an issue. in `nx.dag` `dag` stands for Directed **Acyclic** Graph, and for those types of problems the longest path can be determined "easily". One your graph has a cycle (A -> B -> C - > A) the  problem becomes very complex, which is likely happening when you have A - > A in your problem. I'm not sure how you'd want to deal with those cases. Perhaps filter them out first, try the above and then you can fill them in after?